# D3js collapse objects with duplicate properties

Tags: d3.js

```
var dataset = [
 {'color': 'red', 'amount': 10},
 {'color': 'green', 'amount': 10},
 {'color': 'red', 'amount': 30},
 {'color': 'blue', 'amount': 20}
];
```

I want to collapse dataset into a newDataset array to only have one of each color with the amount property added like this:

```
newDataset = [
 {'color': 'red', 'amount': 40}, //combined 2 rows
 {'color': 'green', 'amount': 10},
 {'color': 'blue', 'amount': 20}
]
```

I am doing this successfully with a for loop in javascript, but would like to know **if there is a d3.js helper function** for cases like this? I can't seem to find one in the documentation, but I am not the best documentation-reader...

Comment: BTW I am using d3.csv to load the data, if that matters.

Comment: `d3.nest()` can help with that: http://bl.ocks.org/phoebebright/raw/3176159

Comment: Looks like .rollup() might be the ticket. Thanks for the clue. I will investigate further and report back.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

d3.nest() is capable of that.

```
d3.nest().key(function(d){return d.color;})
         .rollup(function(a){
              return a.reduce(function(p,c) {
                   return p+c.amount;
              },0)})
         .entries(dataset)
         .reduce(function(p,c) {p.push({ 'color': c.key, 'amount': c.values });return p;},[]);  // <-- added to satisfy comments below.
```

Comment: This will not produce the data structure as requested by OP's `newDataset`.

Comment: Well, it actually does some up the values as one would expect, but have a look at the objects it creates: `{ key: "red", values: 40}`, which are not like the ones requested `{'color': 'red', 'amount': 40}`. This could, of course, be further mapped to the desired result, but I doubt, that this will show any advantages over the pure JS solution mentioned by OP.

Comment: And that is why you downvoted?  Just add a reduce call to remap it.